# extract text between two words using sed

Tags: bash, sed

I want to extract text in shell variable which is in between two matching words/characters, like below.

Input string-

`extract='sometext Query State: FINISHED\n Query Status: OK\n soonnnnnnnnnnnn Query State: STARTING\n'`

I want to extract the query state, which is in between the text 'Query State' and first occurrence of '\n'

I have used below sed expression-

`query_state=$(echo $extract | sed 's/.*Query State: \(.*\)\\n .*/\1/')`

but I get output as -  **`FINISHED\n Query Status: OK`**, 
basically, the above is giving eveything between the the words 'Query Status' and last occurence of '\n'.

So, I changed to sed expression like below to get output **'FINISHED'**

`query_state=$(echo $extract | sed 's/.*Query State: \(.*\)\\n Query Status.*/\1/')`

But above expression is having hard dependency on the text 'Query Status'. How can I change the expression to get exactly at first occurence of '\n' ?

Update:I want to extract the query state, which is in between the **first occurence of text 'Query State' followed by first occurrence of '\n'**

-Thanks

Comment: Could the "Query State: ..." fragment be right at the end of the string, **not** terminated by a `\n` marker? If so, you should state this in your question - some solutions may need to be adjusted to handle that possibility correctly.

Comment: Perhaps `echo -e "$extract"|sed -n '1s/.*: //p'`? use the `-e` to evaluate the echoed string and then use sed to remove the unwanted string in the first line.

Comment: @mathguy I have updated my ask. There can be 'n' no. of 'QUERY STATE' present in my text. I want to extract which is in between the first occurence of text 'Query State' followed by first occurrence of '\n'

Comment: The site etiquette rules say that you shouldn't change your question, after people have already answered your original one. Nobody benefits from the resulting confusion. Post a different question, pointing to this one if needed. With that said, though - I showed you how you can get ALL the occurrences, one per line. To keep just the first one, you can pipe the result to `head -n 1`. Not the most efficient way, perhaps, but if you don't have a lot of data to process, that will suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` solution (since you are only looking to find a match, you are not looking to edit anything):

```
$ echo "$extract"
sometext Query State: FINISHED\n Query Status: OK\n soonnnnnnnnnnnn

$ echo "$extract" | grep -oP '(?<=Query State: ).*?(?=\\n)'
FINISHED
```

Explanation:

`-o` Return only the matched substring (this will return all matches, one per line)

`-P` For perl-compatible regular expressions; needed for lookaround as well as lazy quantifier

`(?<= ... )` **lookbehind** : The match should start at a position immediately following the last character (in this case, the space) between the opening sequence `(?<=` and the closing parenthesis.

`.*?` zero or more characters (*any* characters), **as few as possible**. `*?` is called *lazy* (or *non-greedy*) quantifier.

`(?=\\n)` **lookahead** : Similar to lookbehind. Backslash must be escaped.

**EDIT**:

If the "Query State: ..." fragment may appear at the very end of the string, **not** terminated by the `\n` marker, and if in that case the state must still be returned, the regular expression needs to be modified as follows:

```
$ echo $extract
sometext Query State: FINISHED

$ echo $extract | grep -oP '(?<=Query State: ).*?((?=\\n)|$)'
FINISHED
```

Notice the alternation in the lookahead: we are looking for the substring `\n` **or** the end of the input string; either one will work.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. This is giving values for all QUERY STATE variables present in $extract. I have updated input string and question. I am looking for text which is in between the first occurence of text 'Query State' followed by first occurrence of '\n'

Comment: @no1 - as I said in a comment under your question, this is a breach of forum rules. In any case - the `grep` solution can be modified easily to only get the first occurrence (more efficient than using `head` on the output from the above command). Namely: ............................................................................ `grep -oP '^.*?Query State: \K.*?(?=\\n)'`

Comment: That works like a charm. You may update the above comment in answer to match the updated question.

Answer (score 1):

For a short case you can consider an extra call to `sed`:

```
echo "$extract" | sed -n 's/\\n/\n/g; s/.*Query State: //p'
```

Can you tell anything about the possible values of the state? Another solution can be something like

```
echo "$extract" | sed -r 's/.*Query State: ([A-Za-z ]*).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
extract='sometext Query State: FINISHED\n Query Status: OK\n soonnnnnnnnnnnn' 

echo "$extract" | sed 's/.*Query State: \([^\\n]\+\).*$/\1/'
```

Output

```
FINISHED
```

Works with `awk`

```
echo "$extract" |  awk -F'[: \\\\n]+' '{print $4}'
```

Comment: This may consume a terminal backslash in the required output. Suppose the "state" was the string `'FINISHED\'` (terminated by a backslash, for whatever reason), followed immediately by the `\n` delimiter. Your solution will only show `FINISHED`, not the trailing backslash.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, at least I learned something from this. I'm not good at regexp as you can see :-(